# ActiveMerchant PaypalExpressGateway reference transaction

Tags: paypal, activemerchant

Is there a way to use ActiveMerchant's PaypalEpressGateway to bill for arbitrary amounts without sending the user back to Paypal every time?  It looks like the `reference_transaction` method might support that using a billing agreement, but the documentation doesn't really specify what it requires.

Answer (score -1):

You can contact PayPal support team and they will guide you

Email to contact is ppmts@paypal.com